# Is there an equivalent to Pythons iterator tools for Node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, python-itertools

I'm trying to port some code that uses Python's [iterator tools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to Node, however I'm not seeing any analogs out there.

I'm specifically looking for a replacement for itertools.combination()

I've seen this one, but it's incomplete and out of date: [node-intertools](https://github.com/titarenko/node-itertools)

Comment: ... your link is a 404. Please fix.

Comment: sorry about that, Fixed.

Comment: Haven't tried them but I see there are at least two attempts at itertools in js... https://github.com/peterjkirby/itertoolsjs, https://github.com/cweider/js-itertools/blob/master/itertools.js

Comment: @Stuart Those are more complete, but neither has actually covered all of the original functionality. Looks like I may have to fork them.

Comment: Actually looking through the code for the cweider/js-itertools it seems he isn't porting the Python itertools, it's a seperate project.

Comment: really? cweider seems to have implemented much of itertools such as `chain`, `count`, `cycle`, `repeat`

Comment: Looked at it again, seems to cover roughly half of the api, although some of the names are different for instance `filter` instead of `ifilter`.  Definitely doesn't cover the combinitorial portions, or certain functions like `starmap` or `compress`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was not happy with the available solutions, so I wrote my own:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/iter-tools

Comment: Thanks for answering this.  At the time I was after something that was missing in your package, but it seems to be in there now!