# Itertools.combinations in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a similar library as Python's itertools in JavaScript? I'm interested in permutations and combinations especially.

I'm not using Node.js.

I want to do something like this:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

//return non-duplicate combinations of length 2
['a', 'b']
['a', 'c']
['a', 'd']
['b', 'c']
['b', 'd']
['c', 'd']
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru Could you be more specific ? Can you show an example ? :) Thanks!

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41616364/3551786)

Comment: `array` has unique elements or it can be like `['a','b','c','d','a']` and the result will be the same?

Comment: @bluehipy the accepted answer is what i wanted the rest i can workout but thanks ! :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/wassname/a882ac3981c8e18d2556

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach for gettign the permutation of the given array with a specified size.

```js
function getPermutations(array, size) {

    function p(t, i) {
        if (t.length === size) {
            result.push(t);
            return;
        }
        if (i + 1 > array.length) {
            return;
        }
        p(t.concat(array[i]), i + 1);
        p(t, i + 1);
    }

    var result = [];
    p([], 0);
    return result;
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

console.log(getPermutations(array, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice.  Not sure why this isn't in here this way: https://www.npmjs.com/package/itertools    In theory the same, but the implementation is starkly different than python combinations.

Comment: This algorithm breaks if one of the elements in the array is another array that has a length longer than the requested size

Answer (score 4):

You can use my es-iter library, which is almost one to one port of Python's itertools but in JS way.

https://github.com/abozhilov/ES-Iter#combinationsr

Answer (score 2):

I like `itertools.combinations` and wanted a memory-efficient JavaScript [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), but couldn't quickly find an acceptable library so I rolled my own.

It's in TypeScript (to help me keep track of bookkeeping), but I'll append the transpiled JavaScript at the bottom.

```
function* range(start: number, end: number) {
  for (; start <= end; ++start) { yield start; }
}

function last<T>(arr: T[]) { return arr[arr.length - 1]; }

function* numericCombinations(n: number, r: number, loc: number[] = []): IterableIterator<number[]> {
  const idx = loc.length;
  if (idx === r) {
    yield loc;
    return;
  }
  for (let next of range(idx ? last(loc) + 1 : 0, n - r + idx)) { yield* numericCombinations(n, r, loc.concat(next)); }
}

function* combinations<T>(arr: T[], r: number) {
  for (let idxs of numericCombinations(arr.length, r)) { yield idxs.map(i => arr[i]); }
}
```

All the black magic is in the `numericCombinations` function, which is a recursive generator—see MDN documentation on [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*). The actual `combinations` function just wraps it to match the Python API.

I can put this in a `.ts` file and put this at the bottom of it:

```
if (module === require.main) {
  const shorts = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
  let i = 0;
  for (let o of combinations(shorts, 7)) { i++; }
  console.log(i);
}
```

and Node prints out `133784560` in less than 2.5 minutes, with minimal memory usage, on my 2015-vintage laptop. That is, it generated all *hundred thirty-four million* ways you can choose seven cards from a standard deck of fifty-two playing cards (i.e., all complete Texas hold ’em hands) without burdening memory or overly-nesting recursive function calls.

(Python3 can do this in 20 seconds, or 7× faster… speedups to the above welcome.)

---

JavaScript code:

```
function* range(start, end) {
  for (; start <= end; ++start) { yield start; }
}
function last(arr) { return arr[arr.length - 1]; }
function* numericCombinations(n, r, loc = []) {
  const idx = loc.length;
  if (idx === r) {
    yield loc;
    return;
  }
  for (let next of range(idx ? last(loc) + 1 : 0, n - r + idx)) { yield* numericCombinations(n, r, loc.concat(next)); }
}
function* combinations(arr, r) {
  for (let idxs of numericCombinations(arr.length, r)) { yield idxs.map(i => arr[i]); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cartesian products, you might want to check [this](https://gist.github.com/wassname/a882ac3981c8e18d2556) verbose example that leverages `lodash`. The functionality is similar to [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in Python.

Comment: Cannot access the page because of security. Can you show it somewhere else ? Thanks ! :)