# Javascript recursion: pull all unique combinations of single items from N arrays of M length

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am looking to create a recursive function (or use loops), to select all possible combinations of single items of N arrays, each having M length.

I want to pull out each combination and find the product of the items from the arrays and store the result. So in other words, the order of the items pulled out doesn't matter (for the example, 1, 1, 4 pulled from the first index starting with array1 would be considered the same as 4, 1, 1 pulled from the first index starting with array3 and working backwards).

```js
//Example: 

//in this case, N = 3 and M = 5, 3, 4 for array1, array2, and array3, respectively 

array1 = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7];
array2 = [1, 5, 3];
array3 = [4, 3, 7, 9];

//Example output using arrays above:
[1, 1, 4]
[3, 1, 4]
[5, 1, 4]
[6, 1, 4]
[7, 1, 4]
[1, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
[3, 5, 4]
//etc...
```

I expect the output of each recursive call to be one item from each Array, resulting in a unique combination of items.

For example, each call would output an array of N length, with one value from each array. The function should run until all unique combinations have been looked at.

UPDATE: to clarify, the final end solution that I am trying to get at is to find the Minimum product, by selecting one item from each array and multiplying them together. But I also need to evaluate, manipulate and store each combination, before determining this minimum.

Comment: please add the wanted result and your try.

Comment: I added example output, I haven't gotten far enough that it is worth including my current attempts.. At this point I just know I will likely need to use recursion to get a solution

Comment: It's easy to get a list of combinations, but excluding duplicates would be a pain.

Comment: @cHao use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: what is `M` ment to be?

Comment: @Wendelin: A Set would not work quite so well for arrays. Every array would either be identical or unique, depending on how you do things. Now, if you were to use a Set to only care about the product of each array...

Comment: @cHao oh, yes. Didn't think about it enough

Comment: @NinaScholz M is the length of each Array, which varies. Both the number of Array's and the length of each Array is variable.

Comment: This may help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813439/itertools-combinations-in-javascript

Comment: @cHao please see the UPDATE above, hopefully provides more clarity as to the final solution I am looking for

Comment: If what you really want is just the minimum product, then why not just `Math.min()` on each array and then multiply?

Comment: @benvc: Should work, at least til negative numbers get involved.

Comment: @benvc because I need to evaluate and store each iteration as well, I have added that clarification to the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cou could get the cartesian product first and then get unique products from this values.

The `raw` array contains possible duplicates.

```js
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;

var array1 = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7],
    array2 = [1, 5, 3],
    array3 = [4, 3, 7, 9],
    data = [array1, array2, array3],
    raw = data.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), [])),
    unique = Array.from(new Set(raw.map(a => a.reduce(multiply))));

console.log(unique);
console.log(raw.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write this sort of thing as a composition of functions.  I'm a big fan of [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com) (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author) and with Ramda, this is a one-liner <sup>1</sup>:

```js
const uniqueProduct = pipe (xprod, map (product), unique)
```

Of course you wouldn't want to pull in an external library for a single simple problem, but it's also easy to write our own versions of the functions used here:

```js
// Utility functions
const pipe = (...fns) => (args) => 
  fns .reduce ((a, f) => f (a), args) 
  
const map = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs.map(fn)

const product = (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => a * x, 1)

const crossproduct = (xss) =>
  xss.reduce(
    (ps, xs) => ps.reduce((r, p) => [...r, ...(xs.map((x) => [...p, x]))], []), 
    [[]]
  )

const unique = (xs) => 
  Array .from (new Set (xs))


// Main function
const uniqueProduct = pipe (crossproduct, map (product), unique) 



// Demonstration
const data = [[1, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 5, 3], [4, 3, 7, 9]]

console .log ( 
  uniqueProduct (data)
)
```

Every function here, except for `uniqueProduct` is common enough that there's already a version available in Ramda.  But these versions are also potentially useful across a great deal of your code.  And outside `crossproduct`, they are trivial-to-write functions.

Note that there is no difference here in algorithm from Nina Scholz's answer; it's only structured differently.  I like the fact that, by storing the common functions in my own library or by using a public one, this code can be written so simply.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is actually a bit of an exaggeration.  Ramda's `xprod` function only works on two arrays; I happen to keep handy one that works on an array of arrays in my own personal utility library built atop Ramda.